# Hibernate OneToMany FetchType.EAGER at times is not fetching all the child entities

Tags: hibernate

Hibernate OneToMany is not fetching all the child entities.Some time it is retrieving all the values from the comments list and some times not.
Please help me understand if I am missing some thing.

```
  @Entity
    @Data
    @Table(name = "Post")
    public class Post implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
        @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
        @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
        private String id;

        @Column(name = "name")
        private String postname;


        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy="post",orphanRemoval = true)
        private  List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();

        //getters and setters

    }

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "comments")
public class Comment implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4522532272183748926L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "comment_id", nullable = false)
    private Post post;

    @Column(name = "sequence", nullable = false)
    private Long sequence;
  //getters and setters

}


 When I fetch , comments list from a post.It is retrieving only one comments entity.Even there are more than one.
```

Some times it is giving all the child entities and some times only one.

```
 List<Comment> list = getPost().getComments();
  System.out.println("Size of list : "+getPost().getComments().size()); //giving only 1 comment entity , even there are two entities

        for(int i = 0;i< list.size();i++) {
                            Comment rc = getPost().getComments().get(i);        
                            }
```

This is the method that get the list of Posts from DB.In database there are around 5000 posts and when a particular post(the one which is giving one entity one time and all the entities in different run) is first element of this List , then all of the child entities are retrieved , but when it is some where around the middle of the list only one child entity is retrieved.

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
                public List<Post> getPostList(int firstResult, int maxResult){

                    List<Post> list = null;
                    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
                    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Post.class);

                    try {

                        criteria.setFirstResult(firstResult);
                        criteria.setMaxResults(maxResult);
                        criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("dateCreated"));

                        list=Collections.checkedList(criteria.list(), Post.class);

                    }catch(Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }finally {
                        if(session!=null) {
                            session.close();
                        }
                    }

                    return list;
                }
```

Comment: Please provide example where only 1 comment is fetched and when all of them are fetched.

Comment: Size of the list is showing 1 , some times and in a different run it is showing 2 which is the actual size.But let me know if what I wrote right , in terms if placing of annotations

Comment: I personally think that there is nothing wrong with the code, but with your data. Mapping looks normal

Comment: What if there is no"fetch = FetchType.EAGER" over  private Post post;in Comment class.Will that show the behavior of not retrieving all the child entities

Comment: But that would make comments to be fetched lazy-way resulting in all comments beeing available anyway. I think that your data is incorrect and hibernate shows correct results. You can always try to show us more code.

Comment: Pasted more code.